# What does `setBufferedSize()` method do?

Tags: java, buffer, httpclient

I don't know what `setBufferSize()` method does. can anyone explain me what it does? What happens if i change `setBufferSize(4 * 1024)` to `setBufferSize(5)`? i don't see any change when i do that!!. can anyone explain?
Thanks.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String url = "DOWNLOAD_LINK";
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
            ConnectionConfig connectionConfig = ConnectionConfig.custom()
                    .setBufferSize(4 * 1024).build();

            HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
            builder.setDefaultConnectionConfig(connectionConfig);

            HttpClient client = builder.build();

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
            int len = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4098];
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                System.out.println("len: " + len);
                //write into file , etc.
            }
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quote from the documentation of SetBufferedSize, fairly complete :

> Sets the preferred buffer size for the body of the response. The
>   servlet container will use a buffer at least as large as the size
>   requested. The actual buffer size used can be found using
>   getBufferSize.
>
> A larger buffer allows more content to be written before anything is
>   actually sent, thus providing the servlet with more time to set
>   appropriate status codes and headers. A smaller buffer decreases
>   server memory load and allows the client to start receiving data more
>   quickly.

[Source](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setBufferSize(int))

[Apache's documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/config/ConnectionConfig.Builder.html#setBufferSize(int))

Comment: OP is asking for org.apache.http.config.ConnectionConfig.Builder.setBufferSize()

Comment: @guleryuz The Apache documentation on that method is fairly poor, that's why I chose to include this particuliar link, I can add in the link to the actual "ConnectionConfig" doc but won't really help the OP to understand the point of the buffer size IMO